# UITableViewCell setEditing:animated doesn't get called if cell is the first responder and is offscreen

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a subclass of UITableViewCell with added UITextField to edit the contents of a cell in editing mode.
In my custom cells implementation I have overridden setEditing like this:

```
-(void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    if ([self.textField isFirstResponder])
        [self.textField resignFirstResponder];
    NSLog(@"%@",self.textLabel.text);
    if (editing) {
        self.textLabel.hidden = YES;
        self.textField.hidden = NO;
    }else{
        self.textLabel.hidden = NO;
        self.textField.hidden = YES;
    }

    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
}
```

And what happens is when I call setEditing for first time they all go to editing mode. But if I try to modify cell and if this cell goes offscreen and I tap the "Done" button the cell is still in editing mode. Only the cell that has gone offscreen. If it's visible onscreen when I tap the "Done" button it just works.

Here is a video to better describe the problem: [video on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tfa3jiizwgco4db/bug-textfield.mov)

Comment: Well, would you look at that!  File a bug report, because this one is a biggie.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in your UITableViewController subclass by implementing the following:

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated{    
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    //since setEditing isn't called on cells that are offscreen do this to ensure the keyboard is dismissed.
    [self.view endEditing:editing];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You may try to dismiss the keyboard when the textfield goes off screen